# Iterator value not retained after 'any()' call

Tags: python, iterator, scope

I have the following snippet of code. I'm basically trying to get the index/iterator of a particular string in a list (aside from just knowing whether it is present). Is this possible at all, or should I be using a loop-with-an-if?

bucket = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]

content = ""

if any(content == "beta" for content in bucket):
    print content

Having 'content' as global or simply within the loop did not make a difference

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly.  Are you looking for `bucket.index("beta")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator expressions do not leak the iterator. List comprehensions in 2.x do, but not in 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a generator for searching within the `any` call.  That generator as you have left it is a temporary.  That is, it exists only within the call to `any` so you will not be able to look at it afterwards.  If you want it to come out to the location of the index then do this:

```
item = [x for x in enumerate(bucket) if x[1] == "beta"]
```

which generates the list of all items which match plus the indexes.

Comment: That's not a list comprehension.